# Initializing a new GHCJS project using the Haskell Tool Stack

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, ghcjs

What do I need to do to initialize a GHCJS project using Haskell Stack?

Following the [stack documentation](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/#stack-new) I am trying to initialize a GHCJS project so that I can compile Haskell code to JavaScript.

After doing `stack templates` I see there is a GHCJS template

```
ghcjs - Haskell to JavaScript compiler, based on GHC
```

When I try using the new command with this template like this:

`stack new ghcjsSetup ghcjs`

I get this error message:

```
Downloading template "ghcjs" to create project "ghcjsSetup" in ghcjsSetup/ ...

The following parameters were needed by the template but not provided: author-email, author-name, category, copyright, github-username
You can provide them in /home/u/.stack/config.yaml, like this:
templates:
  params:
    author-email: value
    author-name: value
    category: value
    copyright: value
    github-username: value
Or you can pass each one as parameters like this:
stack new ghcjsSetup ghcjs -p "author-email:value" -p "author-name:value" -p "category:value" -p "copyright:value" -p "github-username:value"

Looking for .cabal or package.yaml files to use to init the project.
Using cabal packages:
- ghcjsSetup/ghcjsSetup.cabal

Selecting the best among 11 snapshots...

* Partially matches lts-9.11
    ghcjs-base not found
        - ghcjsSetup requires -any

Downloaded nightly-2017-11-01 build plan.    
Unable to parse cabal file: FromString "This package requires at least Cabal version 2.0" Nothing
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've got the same error recently. Apparently you've got an old version of `stack`. You need to upgrade it to version `>= 1.5.1`. This error occurs because of some file format changes in `Cabal ver. 2.0` as I think.

Comment: You are right I did not have the most current version of Stack.  I upgraded stack using `stack upgrade` and added the new binary it showed in it's output to my PATH variable.  Then the command `stack new projectName ghcjs` worked and initialized a GHCJS project for me.  Thanks

Comment: It doesn't look like it works any more (v1.7.1) - https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/1390